# extjs 6 grid widget disappears after store commit

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a grid with a combobox in one of the columns which works on first load but when i edit the value of the store for the cell and when i do this

```
onComboOptionsChange: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {

record.set("Unit", 1);
record.commit();

}
```

the grid does not show the combo box anymore.

```
{
header: 'Options',
dataIndex: 'StoreName',
flex: 1,
xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
widget:
    {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    displayField: 'Description',
    valueField: 'LineID',
    listeners: {
        change: 'onComboOptionsChange'
    }
   },
listeners:{
  afterrender:'afterWidgetRender'
}, 
onWidgetAttach: function (column, widget, record) {

  var itemStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      fields: [
                  { name: 'LineID', type: 'int' },
                  { name: 'ServiceCode', type: 'string' },
      ],
      data: record.data.Items
  });

  widget.setStore(itemStore); 

},
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Hey @calalee and  any one found the solution of this above issue.?boz i am also facing the same issue & investigate from last 2 days. please suggest